# Is it better to study semiconductors before electronics devices?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, analog

In my university I have no semiconductor course to study. They make us begin studying electronics devices right away (Topics in microelectronics by sedra). My question is should I study semiconductors first ? or Is it okay to get directly to studying electronic devices ?

Comment: Requests for opinion are off topic. Questions should be answerable on the basis of facts. If you can narrow down your question so that it can be answered with facts, it might be possible to make this into an on-topic question.

Comment: That said, the vast majority of people learn about devices at the circuit level before they learn about the underlying physics. Why are you concerned that this might not be effective? And would you be willing to learn about semiconductors without learning solid-state physics first? Would you be willing to learn solid-state without learning qunatum mechanics first?

Comment: Many of the active members here have taken classes in electronics, solid state physics and so forth, and may have taught them. What topics are covered in what classes, and which are important to a course of study with a particular goal (e.g. get a BSEE and go work on cell phone RF amps) are matters of fact.  I think this question is weak for not being clear on purpose, and not stated in a more general way useful to others in similar situations.

Answer (score 5):

How a transistor or diode behaves can be described entirely at the level of currents, voltages, resistance and capacitance and so on, except for the most subtle fine points.  Electronics-only classes will suffice for this, and for using transistors and other devices effectively in practical circuitry.

*Why* a semiconductor device behaves the way it does, and designing them, does require deeper knowledge including quantum mechanics, condensed matter physics, band theory and all that.